# Reading news feeds from Facebook fails after upgrading graph API 2.0

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-permissions

Hi There is a requirement in my application, where we need to show the user news feeds. For this we were using Facebook permission "read-stream" before Facebook has changed their list of permissions.
Now after they have shifted to the new API v2.0 there are comments saying that

"read_stream permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop, in-car and TV apps will not be granted this permission."

If this is so what is the alternative to make my app fetch news feeds as earlier.
There is a another permission called "User_Posts" which says "Provides access to the posts on a person's Timeline. Includes their own posts, posts they are tagged in, and posts other people make on their Timeline"

But i am not able to see any posts or news feeds in my application when i have replaced "read_stream" with "user_posts".

Answer (score 0):

The alternative is the `user_posts` permission and the `/me/posts` endpoint. Of course this does not return posts of friends for privacy reasons. You can read more about that in the [changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3).

If you don´t get any results, make sure the Access Token includes the `user_posts` permission and debug it in the [Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/).

Comment: No it is not working. API returns back with error saying that post search has been deprecated. :(

Comment: then you are trying to do something completely different and definitely not calling /me/posts. please post your exact api call.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is a weird issue happening now. The API returns the results some times and it returns back with the empty response  some times.